Early 90s TV series about some magic items, "the giant baby" and one bad neighbour?
I remember a TV series from my childhood from the 90's where few teenagers were looking for some magic items to collect, to find someone to be called "the giant baby" (at least this is how the term was translated in Bulgarian).
There were magic slippers, as I remember. Finally the family's dog happened to be that 'giant baby'.
And I think it was the same series, where aliens threatened the Earth and asked for a match sticks model of Sydney's opera.
Is there really tv show or I am just delusional?
